# How to stop computer waking up from sleep when LAN connected

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have a Compaq desktop machine that wakes up from sleep only when the LAN cable is connected to it. The WOL feature is DISABLED in the BIOS, so why does it keep waking up? And why is it getting told to wake up? I was under the impression that an application or service has to specifically send a message to the machine in order to wake it up but I am not aware of any software on my network that would do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Device Manager, then expand Network Adapters, and on the offending adapter (in fact, do this for all them for now) right click, properties, Power Management, and uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer"

Answer (score 0):

Unplugging the computer would solve that problem. There also maybe a cable running from your network card to your motherboard. If you remove it, it may disable WOL.

Answer (score 0):

Often you can disable the feature in the power management section of either windows or your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I spent so long searching for a solution to this problem; i changed all the devices connected to my computer to not allow them to wake the computer when in sleep mode (wake on lan), I updated my bios, and tried numerous different things I found online but it still randomly woke while in sleep mode. After months of no luck i finally came to the solution MOZILLA **FIREFOX**; when Firefox is running and the computer is put to sleep it will wake up but is you close the browser the computer stays asleep. I hope this helps those who have tried everything out there and still cant find the solution.